# Configure Lerna to publish NPM packages to private Gitlab repo

Tags: gitlab, lerna

I'm doing some tests with [Lerna](https://lerna.js.org/) to create a mono-repo with a bunch of packages that I'd like to share with some applications. I've followed Lerna's documentation to setup a project and this is the file structure:

```
- lernatest/
    - lerna.json
    - package.json
    - packages/
        - common
            - src/
                - index.ts
            - .npmrc
            - package.json
        - models
            - src
                - index.ts
            - .npmrc
            - package.json
```

I need to publish the packages to a private project inside my Gitlab account. Before using Lerna, I could do it manually on each package adding a `.npmrc` file with the following content:

```
@mypackages:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/
//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/packages/npm/:_authToken=<TOKEN>
//gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=<TOKEN>
```

And in each `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "@mypackages/common",
  "publishConfig": {
    "@mypackages:registry": "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/packages/npm/"
  }
  (ETC...)
}
```

I don't know how to configure Lerna properly to publish the packages to my Gitlab registry. This is my `lerna.json` file:

```
{
  "version": "0.0.5",
  "packages": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "command": {
    "publish": {
      "registry": "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/packages/npm/"
    }
  }
}
```

But when I run `npx lerna publish`, I get the following error:

```
lerna info publish Publishing packages to npm...
lerna notice Skipping all user and access validation due to third-party registry
lerna notice Make sure you're authenticated properly ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
lerna http fetch PUT 401 https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/packages/npm/@mypackages%2fcommon 462ms
lerna ERR! E401 401 Unauthorized - PUT https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/packages/npm/@mypackages%2fgcommon
```

I've tried searching the documentation but I can't find anything helpful, any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: The error message indicates that you need to authenticate yourself. I think you are using scoped packages (`@scoped/package-name`) ? Am I correct? You need to set a security token: `npm config set '//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<your_project_id>/packages/npm/:_authToken' "<your_token>" ` From the [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/npm_registry/#authenticating-to-the-gitlab-npm-registry)

Comment: Hi! I've set the authentication details in a `.npmrc` file in the root of the project and now it's working. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Great. Nice to hear

Answer (score 10):

It seems that the `.npmrc` files in each package are ignored when publishing. I've created a single `.npmrc` file in the root of the project with the needed authentication data and now it works like a charm.

This is how my `.npmrc` file looks like:

```
@mypackages:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/
//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/packages/npm/:_authToken=<TOKEN>
//gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=<TOKEN>
```

Comment: Please post an example how your `.npmrc` file looks like (without the security token of course)

Comment: Finally, this solved it for me, many thanks for sharing this.